# In Java, Struggling with returning a color

Tags: java, colors, enums

So in my main class I'm doing the following:

```
String myString = msgBlock.getMsg();
Color fColor = Color.WHITE;
msgBlock.setSuppressed(TernarySwitch.ON); /* suppress original message to display new one */
String[] myStringParts = myString.split("\\s+",13); /*divide into 13 parts */
String finalPart = myStringParts[12].toString(); /* print last part */
String fColorMsg     = myStringParts[7].toString();
String[] fColorParts = fColorMsg.split("_",2);
String fColorTxt     = fColorParts[1].toString();
fColor               = Colors.fromString(fColorTxt);
/*MessageBlock mb = new MessageBlock(fColorTxt, Constants.ETOS_ONE_MSG);*/
MessageBlock mb = new MessageBlock(finalPart, Constants.ETOS_ONE_MSG);
mb.setForeground(fColor);
fw.addFilteredMessage(mb);
return msgBlock;
```

I tested using the commented out messageblock and I am getting the color I need in fColorTxt ("GREEN" in my test case).

My Colors.Java looks like this:

```
package com.ibm.tpf.internal;

import java.awt.Color;

public enum Colors{
    BLACK   (  0,   0,   0),
    BLUE    (  0,   0, 255), LIGHT_BLUE    (  0, 128, 255), DARK_BLUE    (  0,   0, 128),
    BROWN   (160,  96,   0), LIGHT_BROWN   (208, 144,   0), DARK_BROWN   ( 96,  32,   0),
    CYAN    (  0, 255, 255), LIGHT_CYAN    (176, 255, 255), DARK_CYAN    (  0, 139, 139),
    GRAY    (128, 128, 128), LIGHT_GRAY    (211, 211, 211), DARK_GRAY    ( 64,  64,  64),
    GREY    (128, 128, 128), LIGHT_GREY    (211, 211, 211), DARK_GREY    ( 64,  64,  64),
    GREEN   (  0, 255,   0), LIGHT_GREEN   (128, 255, 128), DARK_GREEN   (  0, 128,   0),
    MAGENTA (255,   0, 255), LIGHT_MAGENTA (255, 144, 255), DARK_MAGENTA (144,   0, 144),
    MINT    ( 96, 221,  96), LIGHT_MINT    (208, 238, 208), DARK_MINT    ( 16, 187,  16),
    ORANGE  (255, 128,   0), LIGHT_ORANGE  (255, 176,  48), DARK_ORANGE  (192,  64,   0),
    PINK    (255, 192, 203), LIGHT_PINK    (255, 128, 255), DARK_PINK    (231,  84, 128),
    YELLOW  (255, 255,   0), LIGHT_YELLOW  (255, 255, 128), DARK_YELLOW  (160, 160,   0),
    WHITE   (255, 255, 255);

    private int iRed;
    private int iGreen;
    private int iBlue;
    private String text;

    Colors(int iRed, int iGreen, int iBlue) {
        this.iRed   = iRed;
        this.iGreen = iGreen;
        this.iBlue  = iBlue;
    }

    Colors(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }

    public static Color fromString(String text) {
        if (text != null) {
            for (Colors b : Colors.values()) {
                if (text.equalsIgnoreCase(b.text)) {
                    return new Color (b.iRed, b.iBlue, b.iGreen);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I run it, it's not coming out green, it's coming out white.  Any idea why that might be?

Thanks much,

Comment: Please create and then post a [MCVE]. Also, why not give each Colors item a Color field, one calculated from the 3 int constants?

Comment: There seems maybe a fundamental error here? You have two constructors for an enum and neither of them is a convenience constructor for the other. This is setting off alarm bells in my brain. Set all your fields to final and see if you expose any new errors.

Comment: That's it! @Warren has your problem and solution in hand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what finally worked for me.  For some reason, I had a problem comparing text (in effect, "GREEN" != "GREEN" in my system).

```
import java.awt.Color;

public enum Colors{
    BLACK   (  0,   0,   0),
    BLUE    (  0,   0, 255), LIGHT_BLUE    (  0, 128, 255), DARK_BLUE    (  0,   0, 128),
    BROWN   (160,  96,   0), LIGHT_BROWN   (208, 144,   0), DARK_BROWN   ( 96,  32,   0),
    CYAN    (  0, 255, 255), LIGHT_CYAN    (176, 255, 255), DARK_CYAN    (  0, 139, 139),
    GRAY    (128, 128, 128), LIGHT_GRAY    (211, 211, 211), DARK_GRAY    ( 64,  64,  64),
    GREY    (128, 128, 128), LIGHT_GREY    (211, 211, 211), DARK_GREY    ( 64,  64,  64),
    GREEN   (  0, 255,   0), LIGHT_GREEN   (128, 255, 128), DARK_GREEN   (  0, 128,   0),
    MAGENTA (255,   0, 255), LIGHT_MAGENTA (255, 144, 255), DARK_MAGENTA (144,   0, 144),
    MINT    ( 96, 221,  96), LIGHT_MINT    (208, 238, 208), DARK_MINT    ( 16, 187,  16),
    ORANGE  (255, 128,   0), LIGHT_ORANGE  (255, 176,  48), DARK_ORANGE  (192,  64,   0),
    PINK    (255, 192, 203), LIGHT_PINK    (255, 128, 255), DARK_PINK    (231,  84, 128),
    RED     (255,   0,   0), LIGHT_RED     (255, 128, 128), DARK_RED     (128,   0,   0),
    YELLOW  (255, 255,   0), LIGHT_YELLOW  (255, 255, 128), DARK_YELLOW  (160, 160,   0),
    WHITE   (255, 255, 255);

    private int iRed;
    private int iGreen;
    private int iBlue;

    Colors(int iRed, int iGreen, int iBlue) {
        this.iRed   = iRed;
        this.iGreen = iGreen;
        this.iBlue  = iBlue;
    }

    public static Color fromString(String text) {
        if (text != null) {
            Colors ret = Colors.valueOf(text.toUpperCase());
            return new Color (ret.iRed, ret.iGreen, ret.iBlue);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `Colors` enum, the `text` property is always `null`: the constructor

```
Colors(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
```

is never called, since all of your colors are initialized using the other constructor taking RGB values.

Since `text` is always null, this if statement in `fromString` always returns false:

```
if (text.equalsIgnoreCase(b.text))
```

so the method always returns `null`. Then I guess that the rest of the application code considers that `null` color is white.

You have two choices:

- Modify your `Colors` constructor to include the `text` parameter, like this:

  ```
  Colors(int iRed, int iGreen, int iBlue, String text) {
      this.iRed   = iRed;
      this.iGreen = iGreen;
      this.iBlue  = iBlue;
      this.text  = text;
  }
  ```

  Then, each enum declaration would become:

  ```
  BLACK   (  0,   0,   0, "black")
  ```
- Remove the `text` parameter and build your code so that it equals the `name()` of the enum. Then, the `fromString` method becomes:

  ```
  public static Color fromString(String text) {
      if (text != null) {
          for (Colors b : Colors.values()) {
              if (b.name().equalsIgnoreCase(b.text)) {
                  return new Color (b.iRed, b.iBlue, b.iGreen);
              }
          }
      }
      return null;
  }
  ```

Note that you should not return `null` when `fromString` is not able to identify the color. Instead, you should throw a specific exception, like `ColorNotFoundException` or perhaps [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) with a specific message.

Comment: Thank you much for your answer.  I tried using your second option as it's closer to what I'm attempting to do, I think, but it's still not working.  I'm wondering - is there a way to build a getName and a return that I can use to test?  One that will show me whether or not it found the thing?

I'm a complete newb, haven't worked with throwing exceptions yet... guess I'm going to need to learn how to do that next :)

Comment: Ok so I added an else to my if (b.name...) statement, and told it to return another color entirely.  When I ran my program, it gave me my text in that other color - meaning, it's not finding the word "GREEN" in my enum.  any idea why that might be?  I tried adding a trim statement to make sure I have no blanks, but still not getting it.

Comment: If you added the `else` to this if (`if (b.name().equalsIgnoreCase(b.text))`) then it only means "GREEN" is not the first enum (try to see why). The default case (the case where the `text` is not an enum value) is the `return null;` is the snippet above.

Comment: you're right... BUT for some reason it's not returning the color when I take that out..

I tried moving Green to the first enum constant, and still get the other color, so it's definitely not matching string "GREEN" to enum GREEN